# Another word for a place being in 'ruins'

Tags: single-word-requests

What another word for a place being in ruins (figuratively). Like a place hit with a tornado and is now in **____**?

Comment: If a place has been hit with a tornado, it's probably literally in ruins, rather than figuratively.

Comment: Do you want to retain the preposition "in"? That's what I understood. Though, "in ruins" is an idiomatic usage as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*A shambles.*

From the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/177393):

> 5b. pl. … a scene of disorder or devastation; a ruin; a mess. orig. *U.S.*
>
> > 1926   P. H. de Kruif *Microbe Hunters* iii. iv. 83   Once more his laboratory became a shambles of cluttered flasks and hurrying assistants.
> >
> > 1966   M. R. D. Foot *SOE in France* viii. 184   Helped the commandos to make a thorough shambles of the main dockyard.

This derives from another sense of *shambles,* meaning a slaughterhouse or a similarly bloody scene.

Answer (score 3):

The place is *devastated*. It has been *ravaged*.

If, instead of a tornado hitting it, it is falling apart due to age and neglect it could be *dilapidated*.

Answer (score 2):

The place is now **reduced to rubble**.

The place is now **in tatters**.
*or*
The place has been **left in tatters**.

The place is now in a state of complete **disarray**.

Comment: In the words of Mick Jagger, Sh-sh-shattered. Shadoobie.

Answer (score 1):

This place is now [***torn to shreds***](http://jomotornadoblog.blogspot.fr/2011_05_01_archive.html).

This place is now [***ripped to pieces***](http://careyford.com/theologicalstudies/PhilosophicalWritings/IntroToPhil/EvilAndSffrng.html).

This place is now [***an urban wasteland***](http://thebluesuitcase.blogspot.fr/2009/08/postcard-from-troposphere-continued-our.html).

Answer (score 1):

torn asunder
wrecked
obliterated

Answer (score 1):

I use the word shambles - a state of total disorder.

other near words are falling to pieces, wrecked, ramshackles...

Answer (score 1):

[dilapidated](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Dilapidated)

> Having fallen into a state of disrepair or deterioration, as through neglect; broken-down and shabby.

or

[decayed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Decayed)

> A gradual deterioration to an inferior state: urban decay.
>
> Fallen into ruin.

Comment: Decay and dilapidation take time. They're not something I would consider the result of a tornado. I think @BenKovit has the best answer here.